# Switch: duplicate case

Tags: java, duplicates, switch-statement, case

I am trying to write a method to filter content from a list, with criteria determined inside a Map. I wrote a loop over the Map, every time checking if the list element should be added to the new list.
My problem is: in the switch statement, the first and last cases are seen as duplicate. Is it a problem from my IDE? 
Thanks a lot for your help!

```
    @Override
    public boolean match(Person p, Map<String, Object> criteria,SearchMode mode) {
        for(Entry<String,Object> es:criteria.entrySet()) {
            Object value=es.getValue();

            switch(es.getKey()) {
                case ID:        
                    if(mode==SearchMode.AND && !Integer.valueOf(p.getId()).equals((Integer)value)) {
                        return false;
                    }else if (mode==SearchMode.OR && Integer.valueOf(p.getId()).equals((Integer)value)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
                case USER_NAME:
                    if(mode==SearchMode.AND && !p.getUserName().equals(value)) {
                        return false;
                    } else if(mode==SearchMode.OR && p.getUserName().equals(value)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
                case EMAIL:
                    if(mode==SearchMode.AND && !p.getEmail().equals(value)) {
                        return false;
                    }else if(mode==SearchMode.OR && p.getEmail().equals(value)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
                case PASSWORD:
                    if(mode==SearchMode.AND && !p.getPassword().equals(value)) {
                        return false;
                    } else if(mode==SearchMode.OR && p.getPassword().equals(value)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
                case FIRST_NAME:
                    if(mode==SearchMode.AND && !p.getFirstName().equals(value)) {
                        return false;
                    } else if(mode==SearchMode.OR && p.getFirstName().equals(value)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
                case LAST_NAME:
                    if(mode==SearchMode.AND && !p.getLastName().equals(value)) {
                        return false;
                    }else if(mode==SearchMode.OR && p.getLastName().equals(value)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
                case STATUS:
                    if(mode==SearchMode.AND && !p.getStatus().equals((Person.Status.valueOf(value.toString())))){
                        return false;
                    }else if(mode==SearchMode.OR && !p.getStatus().equals((Person.Status.valueOf(value.toString())))){
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: you must have defined constants ID and STATUS. I think the values of these constants are same

Comment: ID and STATUS are not the same. The strange part of this is, the red underlining goes as I reduce the number of cases...

Answer (score 1):

If the business logic in both cases is identical, you can change this:

```
switch(type) {
 case CASE_1: performA(); break;
 case CASE_2: performB(); break;
 case CASE_3: performA(); break;
}
```

where obviously CASE_1 and CASE_3 execute the same code, into this, using the waterfall principle:

```
switch(type) {
  case CASE_1: // no break statement here
  case CASE_3: performA(); break;
  case CASE_2: performB(); break;
}
```

From a functional point of view, this is the same, you just don't have duplicated code to worry about.

But, there is no harm in keeping it the way it is, unless you later on have to update it, and forget to update it for both.

Comment: I finally solved the problem by using enum instead of static final attributes. Seems to work, this time no matter how many they are.